# Material UI / React - fade out component when it unmounts via timeout in parent's useEffect hook

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, material-ui

I have a child component `<Welcome />` which I'd like to add a fade out transition using Material ui Fade component.
I want to be able to hide it on two conditions:

1. if the useEffect's timeout is reached
2. if the user clicks upon the a different element (`Pano` in this case)

I initially had my component controlling it's own state logic, but realized in order to make the second condition possible, I needed to place the conditional logic in the parent and pass the props down.
Code is:

```
function App() {
 const [isVisible, setIsVisible] = useState(true);

 useEffect(() => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      setIsVisible(false);
    }, 8000);
  }, []);

return (
<div>
  <Fade in={isVisible} exit={!isVisible}>
    <Welcome setIsVisible={isVisible} isVisible={isVisible} />
  </Fade>
  <Pano ... />
</div>
```

and the child component to fade in/out:

```
export const Welcome = (props) => {
  const shown = props.isVisible

  return shown ? (
    <div className="wrapper">
      <img src={...} alt="welcome instructions" />
      <p>Click and drag to explore.</p>
      <p>Select icons for more information.</p>
    </div>
  ) : <div />;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Ended up swapping to [Framer Motion](https://www.framer.com/api/) for this. Realized I just wanted the exit animation since I already had a soft blinking to the component when it's loaded in which I could fade slower on the first keyframe. Framer's `<AnimatePresence>` worked just fine for this with a timeout.